# Mongoid MapReduce error with forEach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

```
The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=557
  @request_id=4
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="pracker_development.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:mapreduce=>"pixels", :map=>"\n
  function() {\n
    if(this.tags){\n
      this.tags.forEach(function(tag){\n
        emit(tag, 1)\n
      });\n
    }\n
    }\n          ", :reduce=>"\n
  function(key, values) {\n
    var tag_count = 0 ;\n
    values.forEach(function(value) {\n
      tag_count += value;\n
    });\n
    return tag_count;\n
    }\n          ", :query=>{}, :out=>{:inline=>true}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 9014: "exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: this.tags.forEach is not a function nofile_b:2"

See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md
for details about this error.
```

With Pixel.all_tags this error occurs

### I had this in the past, but the only solution I could come up with was to delete the collection and start over...

github issue:
https://github.com/chebyte/mongoid-simple-tags/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

I think that tags may not be set on all documents. In which case it may be undefined and therefore have no forEach method.

One way to get around this is to pass a query to the map/reduce command that specify the tags field must exist:

`{ query : { tags : { '$exists': true } } }`

You can also check to see if it's an array by checking its type if it could possibly not be an array as well.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll try and see if that fixes it. If it does I'll submit a pull request on the mongoid-simple-tags repo.